# Split data.frame by column with non-sequential values handled as separate groups

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Hi I'm trying to split my data.frame in R (into a list of data.frames) based on a column but so that if the values change in that column and then return they are treated as separate groups and split from each other.

For example here is a very simple reproducible example.

```
Testdf <- data.frame(x= 1:20,test = rep(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),each = 5))
```

I can split normally:

```
Testdf %>% split(.$test)
```

but then the `TRUE`s 1:5 are grouped with `TRUE`s from 11:15, I want the equivalent of

```
Testdf %>% split(rep(1:4,each = 5))
```

but my real data is very complex and there is no standard group size or such things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main key is to create proper groups to `split`

One alternative is to Use `data.table::rleid` to `split`

```
split(Testdf, data.table::rleid(Testdf$test))


#$`1`
#  x test
#1 1 TRUE
#2 2 TRUE
#3 3 TRUE
#4 4 TRUE
#5 5 TRUE

#$`2`
#    x  test
#6   6 FALSE
#7   7 FALSE
#8   8 FALSE
#9   9 FALSE
#.....
```

---

A pure base R alternative if you have only `TRUE`/`FALSE` value is by using `diff`

```
split(Testdf, cumsum(c(0, diff(Testdf$test)) != 0))
```

and another one with `rle`

```
split(Testdf, with(rle(Testdf$test), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))
```

Comment: Ah nice. This does remind me that I have used `rle` in the past to do a similar thing, but I've always found it confusing to use. `data.table::rleid` is a very nice alternative that I've never come across before and will do the trick. Thanks